# Creating entity as "Archived" in postRemove or preRemove

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

### Context

I currently have and entity `Request` which has a collection of `Approval` entities.

My goal is to *archive* the approval once they are removed from the `Request`.

I tried to make it work within an Event Listener using the `@preRemove` or the `@postRemove` (even though it is a bad practice to work in the database in the `postRemove` event, but I tried for the sake of it).

### Issue

But I am unable to get it to work in neither of those unless I only have 1 record to archive. As soon as I have 2 records, it will throw an exception.

**`@postRemove` exception** - It tries to delete the same `Approval` twice.

> Notice: Undefined index: 0000000061b600620000000079e76cab

**`@preRemove` exception** - It tries to persist an empty `ArchivedApproval`.

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO tblArchivedApprovals ([Level], RequestedOn, ApprovalStatus, ApproverComments, ApprovedOn, ApprovedAmount, ApproverID, RequestedBy, ApprovedBy, DeductionID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)':
>
> SQLSTATE [07002, 0]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

**`@preRemove` query:**

```
INSERT INTO tblArchivedApprovals
    ([Level], RequestedOn, ApprovalStatus, ApproverComments, ApprovedOn, ApprovedAmount, ApproverID, RequestedBy, ApprovedBy, DeductionID)
VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Parameters: []
```

Any thoughts on how to do this would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** Here's the listener class as requested:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\EventListener;

use App\Entity\Approval;
use App\Entity\ArchivedApproval;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class ApprovalListener
{

    /**
     * Archive the approval(s) to the approval history before removing them
     *
     * @ORM\PostRemove
     *
     * @param Approval $approval
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $event
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     */
    public function postRemove(Approval $approval, LifecycleEventArgs $event): void
    {
        // Create and set values
        $archivedApproval = new ArchivedApproval();
        $archivedApproval->setDeductionRequest($approval->getDeductionRequest());
        $archivedApproval->setRequestedOn($approval->getRequestedOn());
        $archivedApproval->setRequestedBy($approval->getRequestedBy());
        $archivedApproval->setApprover($approval->getApprover());
        $archivedApproval->setLevel($approval->getLevel());

        if (null !== $approval->getStatus()) {
            $archivedApproval->setStatus($approval->getStatus());
            $archivedApproval->setApproverComments($approval->getApproverComments());
            $archivedApproval->setApprovedAmount($approval->getApprovedAmount());
            $archivedApproval->setApprovedBy($approval->getApprovedBy());
            $archivedApproval->setApprovedOn($approval->getApprovedOn());
        }

        // Save the approval history
        /** @var EntityManager $em */
        $em = $event->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($archivedApproval);
        $em->flush($archivedApproval);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of your listener.

Comment: @dbrumann I just added the `postRemove` following your request. I can also post the `preRemove` if needed, but the only difference is that I don't do the `flush()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Current Solution (not optimal)**

My only way of doing it as of now is to add the `ArchivedApproval` entity into the `Request` entity's `removeApproval` function, but I have to loop through the approvals and remove them one by one instead of simply calling `$request->getApprovals()->clear();`.